# Which are more performant, CTE or temporary tables?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, common-table-expression

Which are more performant, `CTE` or `Temporary Tables`?

Comment: Related question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13112

Comment: Users can find background information (not relating to performance) in the [Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) page on technet.microsoft.com.

Comment: Anyone finding this beware, this is SQL SERVER specific, I found it googling redshift... which is based on postgres.  Postgres treats CTEs as temp tables, while MSSQL treats them as views, and god only knows what redshift is doing under the hood...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'd say they are different concepts but not too different to say "chalk and cheese".

- A temp table is good for re-use or to perform multiple processing passes on a set of data.
- A CTE can be used either to recurse or to simply improved readability. 
  And, like a view or inline table valued function can also be treated like a macro to be expanded in the main query
- A temp table is another table with some rules around scope

I have stored procs where I use both (and table variables too)

Comment: Temp tables also allows for Indexes and even Statistics which are sometimes necessary, while a CTE does not.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't highlight enough the fact that CTE's can lead to terrible performance. I usually refer to this [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/65699) on dba.stackexchange. Your question comes up second in my search engine if I'm looking up `cte vs temporary tables` so IMHO this answer needs to highlight the drawbacks of CTE's better. TL;DR of the linked answer: *a CTE should never be used for performance.*. I agree with that quote as I've experienced the downsides of CTE's.

Comment: @TT.  Interesting.  I find that CTEs perform much better

Comment: This is a pretty old q/a, but came up near the top of my search so just wanted to add a point in favor of CTEs that hasn't been mentioned here: they can be used in views, temp tables and table variables can't.

Comment: @CodeCowboyOrg A CTE *does* have access to the stats and indexes in the table(s) it references, and information about the CTE and the main query are shared since they're in the same execution context. This isn't true for a temporary table.

Answer (score 268):

It depends.

First of all

**What is a Common Table Expression?**

A (non recursive) CTE is treated very similarly to other constructs that can also be used as inline table expressions in SQL Server. Derived tables, Views, and inline table valued functions. Note that whilst BOL says that a CTE "can be thought of as temporary result set" this is a purely logical description. More often than not it is not materlialized in its own right.

**What is a temporary table?**

This is a collection of rows stored on data pages in tempdb. The data pages may reside partially or entirely in memory. Additionally the temporary table may be indexed and have column statistics.

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE T(A INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, B INT , F CHAR(8000) NULL);

INSERT INTO T(B)
SELECT TOP (1000000)  0 + CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(4))
FROM master..spt_values v1,
     master..spt_values v2;
```

**Example 1**

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT A,
       ABS(B) AS Abs_B,
       F
FROM T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE1
WHERE A = 780
```

[image: Plan 1]

Notice in the plan above there is no mention of CTE1. It just accesses the base tables directly and is treated the same as

```
SELECT A,
       ABS(B) AS Abs_B,
       F
FROM   T
WHERE  A = 780
```

Rewriting by materializing the CTE into an intermediate temporary table here would be massively counter productive.

Materializing the CTE definition of

```
SELECT A,
       ABS(B) AS Abs_B,
       F
FROM T
```

Would involve copying about 8GB of data into a temporary table then there is still the overhead of selecting from it too.

**Example 2**

```
WITH CTE2
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A) AS RN
         FROM   T
         WHERE  B % 100000 = 0)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE2 T1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) *
                    FROM   CTE2 T2
                    WHERE  T2.A > T1.A
                    ORDER  BY T2.A) CA
```

The above example takes about 4 minutes on my machine.

Only 15 rows of the 1,000,000 randomly generated values match the predicate but the expensive table scan happens 16 times to locate these.

[image]

This would be a good candidate for materializing the intermediate result. The equivalent temp table rewrite took 25 seconds.

```
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A) AS RN
FROM   T
WHERE  B % 100000 = 0

SELECT *
FROM   #T T1
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) *
                    FROM   #T T2
                    WHERE  T2.A > T1.A
                    ORDER  BY T2.A) CA
```

[image: With Plan]

Intermediate materialisation of part of a query into a temporary table can sometimes be useful even if it is only evaluated once - when it allows the rest of the query to be recompiled taking advantage of statistics on the materialized result. An example of this approach is in the SQL Cat article [When To Break Down Complex Queries](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/when-to-break-down-complex-queries/ba-p/305154).

In some circumstances SQL Server will use a spool to cache an intermediate result, e.g. of a CTE, and avoid having to re-evaluate that sub tree. This is discussed in the (migrated) Connect item [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891374-provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materializati). However no statistics are created on this and even if the number of spooled rows was to be hugely different from estimated is not possible for the in progress execution plan to dynamically adapt in response (at least in current versions. Adaptive Query Plans may become possible in the future).

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the actual question (which is asking which has better performance not what is the difference or which is your favorite), and it answers that question correctly: "It depends" is the right answer. It is also the only answer with supporting data to explain, several others (with high numbers of votes) make definite claims that one is better than the other with no references or proof... To be clear, all of those answers are also **wrong**. Because "It depends"

Comment: It is also a well written, well referenced answer.  Seriously top notch.

Comment: I love to highlight this part which I found to be true

Intermediate materialisation of part of a query into a temporary table can sometimes be useful even if it is only evaluated once

Comment: Something is missing here. The `INSERT INTO #T SELECT ...` statement won't create the `#T` table, so it must've been created explicitly. The execution plan shown here says that the plan is using a clustered index in `#T`, which means the temporary table further has a clustered index on it ... which means that the time to build the table and the index are going to be kind of pricey, but don't seem to be included in this analysis.

Comment: @MikeB - The execution plan for the INSERT is shown. The source table already provides the rows in the order needed for the clustered index (and the insert is only 16 rows anyway). The CREATE TABLE would have been `CREATE TABLE #T(A INT PRIMARY KEY, B INT , F CHAR(8000) NULL, RN INT);` Rerunning it now I do get considerably faster timings for everything than 10 years ago but the point still stands that Query 1 is an order of magnitude slower than Query 2 + Query 3 combined https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwZTL.png (3.748 seconds vs 0.385s + 0.000s)

Comment: Slight clarification - it was 16 rows inserted in the plan linked in the comment above but even that was unlucky. Most random integer generations of   `B` with 1 million rows the the `% 100000=0` would be even less. So probably 10 rows inserted would be average.

Comment: @MartinSmith The plan for the select (without the CTE) is also shown, and that's what I'm looking at. It says that a clustered index scan is being done on `#T` for one inpt to the nested loops join, and a clustered index seek on the other. The name of the index starts `[PK__#T___...` and looks machine generated, implying it was created for a `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: @MikeB - yes. See the `CREATE TABLE #T` in the comment above. It has a PK constraint. The insert into the table with the index and the subsequent usage of that table combined was cheaper than not materializing it  (not that the index makes much difference here anyway either to the `insert` or `select` as the temp table only has < 20 rows in it anyway)

Comment: The time consuming part of the query is identifying the handful of rows out of the 1,000,000 8KB rows that match the condition. And the advantage of materialisation here is that this searching for needles in a haystack is only done once rather than `n` times - the actual insert of the handful of rows takes negligible time. The query 2 here that did the insert took 0.385 seconds https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwZTL.png spent and spent 0.384 seconds of that on downstream operators to the insert (i.e. the identification of matching rows once).

Comment: Point is, the presented execution plan doesn't match the given script which is confusing.  Indeed, the query spends most of its time scanning the `T` table. That takes a long time because the clustered index is bloated with an unused `CHAR(8000)` column, so row read density is poor. That performance is not a problem with CTEs. Instead, it is a problem with poor physical model design. Consider instead `CREATE INDEX IDX_TB on T(B);`, which will make for a far better scan. Or an index on a computed column that matches the modulo in the `WHERE` clause. Or dropping the unused column.

Comment: @MikeB - It is a simple contrived example of where the upfront cost of materialising the CTE pays for itself by reducing the repeated re-evaluations that a CTE would give. This is just an example where the contrived expensive operation could be replaced with some other more realistic expensive to re-evaluate sub tree. The point of it is that many people believe that this materialisation already happens and it will only be evaluated once. RE: "problem with CTEs" - sorry If you are a CTE fan boy but the answer is still "it depends" - and I'm done discussing this

Answer (score 61):

CTE has its uses - when data in the CTE is small and there is strong readability improvement as with the case in recursive tables. However, its performance is certainly no better than table variables and when one is dealing with very large tables, temporary tables significantly outperform CTE. This is because you cannot define indices on a CTE and when you have large amount of data that requires joining with another table (CTE is simply like a macro). If you are joining multiple tables with millions of rows of records in each, CTE will perform significantly worse than temporary tables.

Comment: I've seen this from my own experience.  CTE's perform significantly slower.

Comment: CTE's also perform slower because the results are not cached.  So everytime you use the CTE it re-runs the query, plan and all.

Comment: And the db engine may choose to re-run the query not only every reference, but for every _row_ of the consumer query, as a correlated subquery... you must always watch out for that if it is not desired.

Comment: The temp table is stored in tempdb on SQL Server , which is disk but has the benefit of being indexed and SQL optimizer works well on select queries in that case. Not sure on which db or disk area the CTE is stored (when it exceeds the memory size and is queued for IO paging)but its never optimzed with the large volume of data. I have used the compiler option (with recompile) sometimes to make it faster

Answer (score 42):

Temp tables are always on disk - so as long as your CTE can be held in memory, it would most likely be faster (like a table variable, too).

But then again, if the data load of your CTE (or temp table variable) gets too big, it'll be stored on disk, too, so there's no big benefit.

In general, I prefer a CTE over a temp table since it's gone after I used it. I don't need to think about dropping it explicitly or anything.

So, no clear answer in the end, but personally, I would prefer CTE over temp tables.

Comment: In the case of SQLite and PostgreSQL, temporary tables *are* automatically dropped (usually at the end of a session). I don't know about other DBMS though.

Comment: CTE is like a temp view. AFAIK data isn't stored so nothing van be held in memory or stored on disk. Important note, everytime you use the CTE the query runs again.

Comment: Personally I have never seen a CTE work better than a Temp table for speed. And well debugging is much easier with temp table

Answer (score 9):

So the query I was assigned to optimize was written with two CTEs in SQL server.  It was taking 28sec.

I spent two minutes converting them to temp tables and the query took 3 seconds

I added an index to the temp table on the field it was being joined on and got it down to 2 seconds

Three minutes of work and now its running 12x faster all by removing CTE.  I personally will not use CTEs ever they are tougher to debug as well.

The crazy thing is the CTEs were both only used once and still putting an index on them proved to be 50% faster.

Answer (score 8):

I've used both but in massive complex procedures have always found temp tables better to work with and more methodical. CTEs have their uses but generally with small data.

For example I've created sprocs that come back with results of large calculations in 15 seconds yet convert this code to run in a CTE and have seen it run in excess of 8 minutes to achieve the same results.

Comment: Yes I love this comment.  There seems to be this odd paradigm that if I can write something with one line of code instead of two I should.  I am debugging something right now that has 13 CTE's nested in it and the CTEs are called data1-data13.  Total insanity.

Answer (score 7):

CTE won't take any physical space. It is just a result set we can use join.

Temp tables are temporary. We can create indexes, constrains as like normal tables for that we need to define all variables.

Temp table's scope only within the session.
EX:
Open two SQL query window

```
create table #temp(empid int,empname varchar)
insert into #temp 
select 101,'xxx'

select * from #temp
```

Run this query in first window
then run the below query in second window you can find the difference.

```
select * from #temp
```

Comment: >> "it is just a result set we can use join." -> This is not accurate. CTE is not a a "result set" but inline code. SQL Server query engine parse the CTE code as part of the query text and build an execution plan according. The idea that CTE is inline is the big advantage of using CTE, since it allows the server to create a "combine execution plan"

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but...

The environment I work in is highly constrained, supporting some vendor products and providing "value-added" services like reporting.  Due to policy and contract limitations, I am not usually allowed the luxury of separate table/data space and/or the ability to create permanent code [it gets a little better, depending upon the application].

IOW, I *can't* usually develop a stored procedure or UDFs or temp tables, etc.  I pretty much have to do everything through MY application interface (Crystal Reports - add/link tables, set where clauses from w/in CR, etc.).  One SMALL saving grace is that Crystal allows me to use COMMANDS (as well as SQL Expressions).  Some things that aren't efficient through the regular add/link tables capability can be done by defining a SQL Command.  I use CTEs through that and have gotten very good results "remotely".  CTEs also help w/ report maintenance, not requiring that code be developed, handed to a DBA to compile, encrypt, transfer, install, and then require multiple-level testing.  I can do CTEs through the local interface.

The down side of using CTEs w/ CR is, each report is separate.  Each CTE must be maintained for each report.  Where I can do SPs and UDFs, I can develop something that can be used by multiple reports, requiring only linking to the SP and passing parameters as if you were working on a regular table.  CR is not really good at handling parameters into SQL Commands, so that aspect of the CR/CTE aspect can be lacking.  In those cases, I usually try to define the CTE to return enough data (but not ALL data), and then use the record selection capabilities in CR to slice and dice that.

So... my vote is for CTEs (until I get my data space).

Answer (score 5):

One use where I found CTE's excelled performance wise was where I needed to join a relatively complex Query on to a few tables which had a few million rows each.

I used the CTE to first select the subset based of the indexed columns to first cut these tables down to a few thousand relevant rows each and then joined the CTE to my main query. This exponentially reduced the runtime of my query.

Whilst results for the CTE are not cached and table variables might have been a better choice I really just wanted to try them out and found the fit the above scenario.

Comment: Also, I think since i only use the CTE in the join I only really execute the CTE once in my query so caching the results was not such a big issue in this respect

Answer (score 4):

I just tested this- both CTE and non-CTE (where the query was typed out for every union instance) both took ~31 seconds.  CTE made the code much more readable though- cut it down from 241 to 130 lines which is very nice.  Temp table on the other hand cut it down to 132 lines, and took FIVE SECONDS to run.  No joke.  all of this testing was cached- the queries were all run multiple times before.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really open ended question, and it all depends on how its being used and the type of temp table (Table variable or traditional table).

A traditional temp table stores the data in the temp DB, which does slow down the temp tables; however table variables do not.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience in SQL Server,I found one of the scenarios where CTE outperformed Temp table

I needed to use a DataSet(~100000) from a complex Query just ONCE in my stored Procedure.

- Temp table was causing an overhead on SQL where my Procedure was
  performing slowly(as  Temp Tables are real materialized tables that
  exist in tempdb and Persist for the life of my current procedure)
- On the other hand, with CTE,  CTE Persist only until the following
  query is run. So, CTE is a handy in-memory structure with limited
  Scope. CTEs don't use tempdb by default.

This is one scenario where CTEs can really help simplify your code and Outperform Temp Table.
I had Used 2 CTEs, something like

```
WITH CTE1(ID, Name, Display) 
AS (SELECT ID,Name,Display from Table1 where <Some Condition>),
CTE2(ID,Name,<col3>) AS (SELECT ID, Name,<> FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN Table2 <Some Condition>)
SELECT CTE2.ID,CTE2.<col3>
FROM CTE2
GO
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be very generic... How do you measure that "CTE outperformed Temp table"? Have you got some time measurements? In my opinion you should edit your answer and add more details.

Comment: Yes i have time measurements and Execution plan to support my statement.

Comment: Cannot add the img for execution plan because of limited privileges.Will update details once it is resolved