# With CTE is same like temp tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using **"WITH CTE"** inside my trigger. So if many users came into my web app, does the performance will be slow. Droping will be automatically happen. Will creation and droping of CTE is more costlier. Is is advisable?

How much can i store using WITH CTE?

Is it same like TEMPORARY TABLE?

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is not a temp table, it's basically a subquery or derived table.

Using a CTE can make your code easier to read

There are some good answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/690465/27535)