# SQL Server view or table-valued function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, user-defined-functions

Anyone have a good decisioning tree for deciding when to use a view and when to use a table-valued function in SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe, I could re-phrase the question.   I can easily accomplish what I need to do by using either a view or a table valued function.  Is the rule of thumb to use a view then?

Comment: Yes, if its a real ordinary view and you aren't using fancy tricks like OPENROWSET or CONTEXT_INFO.

Comment: See also [table-valued function vs view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960137/table-valued-function-vs-view/4960468#4960468)

Comment: JonH, if people didn't compare things which appear to do the same thing, then they wouldnt know where to use one over another.  A pig headed comment If ever I saw one.  His question is perfectly valid

Answer (score 13):

Although any view can almost trivially be converted to an inline table-valued function, the converse is not true.

If the construct needs to be parametrized, then use an inline table-valued function.  Inline table-value functions are basically parametrized views in terms of the optimizer being able to combine them with views and push things around.  Multi-statement table-valued functions are not at all like inline table-valued functions.

If you cannot do it with an inline table-valued function, use a multi-statement table-valued function.

Answer (score 2):

There's certain things you can't do in a view (such as table variables, intermediate results before you return your result-set, etc.) ... if you don't need those, view, if you do, sproc/udf :-)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'll give the use we do. We have the tables, but we never access the tables, but the views about the tables. It's just a security issue.