# Microsoft SQL Server Report builder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm building a report using a stored procedure (Haven't done this before), this is the error i get when i run query from the report builder. But it works perfectly from sql server

"An error occurred while executing the query.
There is already an object named 'TempResult' in the database.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

There is already an object named 'TempResult' in the database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2714)"

Comment: Post your query . This error because you already have object with name `TempResult`  in database. And may be in  your query you are trying to create it again.

Comment: What is `TempResult`?

Comment: its a table i created "CREATE TABLE TempResult (CustomerID BIGINT,CUAccountID BIGINT,RepaymentDate DATE,ValueDate DATE,InterestRepayment Money,InterestAmtPaid Money,LoanRepayment money,LoanRepaymentPaid money,Score bit)"

Comment: There is your problem. Once it has been created you cannot create it again.  If you meant for it to be a temp table add # to the name  `#TempResult ` then drop it after you are done with it.

Comment: If you need temporary table to store some data at the time of manipulating then you should use the [temporary tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991511/sql-server-temp-table-vs-table-variable).

Comment: That worked, thanks guys... However after running the query and getting the result, when i click "next" to continue my report design, I get another error  "There was an error executing the query. Nullable object must have a value"

Comment: If you run the SP in SSMS do you see any `NULL`'s (probably date fields, in my experience it is often date fields)

Comment: All date fields fields return values when run in ssms. I have **@Valuedate and @repaymentdate but these fields get values from the db based on the @CustomerID**

Comment: **SET @Valuedate=(Select Cast(ValueDate as Date) as Valuedate from #TempCUTran where CUTransactionID=@CUTransactionID);
   
  Select @RepaymentDate=Cast(RepaymentDate as Date),
     @TotalRepayment=TotalRepayment,
     @InterestRepayment=InterestRepayment,
     @InterestAmtPaid=InterestAmtPaid,
     @LoanRepayment=LoanRepayment,
     @LoanRepaymentPaid=LoanRepaymentPaid
     From CULoanSchedule where ScheduleID=@ScheduleID 
         
   If(@ValueDate<=@RepaymentDate)
 
   BEGIN 
   
   SET @Score=1;
         
         SET @Amount=0.00;**