# Is it possible to create a temporary table in a View and drop it after select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to alter one view and I want to introduce 2 temporary table before the SELECT.

Is this possible? And how can I do it?

```
ALTER VIEW myView
AS 

SELECT *
INTO #temporary1

SELECT *
INTO #temporary2

SELECT * FROM #temporary1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM #temporary1

DROP TABLE #temporary1
DROP TABLE #temporary2
```

When I attempt this it complains that ALTER VIEW must be the only statement in the batch.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just union the select-statements that goes in to each temptable?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

No, a view consists of a single `SELECT` statement. You cannot create or drop tables in a view.

Maybe a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) (CTE) can solve your problem. CTEs are temporary result sets that are defined within the execution scope of a single statement and they can be used in views.

Example (taken from [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/viewwithcte/)) - you can think of the `SalesBySalesPerson` CTE as a temporary table:

```
CREATE VIEW vSalesStaffQuickStats
AS
  WITH SalesBySalesPerson (SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders, MostRecentOrderDate)
      AS
      (
            SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(*), MAX(OrderDate)
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
            GROUP BY SalesPersonID
      )
  SELECT E.EmployeeID,
         EmployeeOrders = OS.NumberOfOrders,
         EmployeeLastOrderDate = OS.MostRecentOrderDate,
         E.ManagerID,
         ManagerOrders = OM.NumberOfOrders,
         ManagerLastOrderDate = OM.MostRecentOrderDate
  FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E
  INNER JOIN SalesBySalesPerson AS OS ON E.EmployeeID = OS.SalesPersonID
  LEFT JOIN SalesBySalesPerson AS OM ON E.ManagerID = OM.SalesPersonID
GO
```

### Performance considerations

[Which are more performant, CTE or temporary tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205087/95)

Comment: The problem is though, depending on what you're trying to do, is that the CTE is re-evaluated for every record in the SELECT. This still can have a huge performance hit. Would love a way for CTE to run "once" and the results used over and over, like a temporary table

Comment: @Fandango68 Good point! I have just linked https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205087/95 for everyone who wants to analyze it deeper.

Comment: Well the good thing about views is that performance is not really an issue as they usually run the background so there is no need for temp tables as CTEs can still do the job, just a lot slower. Now if the CTEs are timing–out and the view cannot refresh then yes we do run into another issue there. In this case, it is better to add a view within a view

Comment: @Fandango68 is right, I compared the CTE approach to INNER JOIN using a table with 20k records, joining the table to itself to filter out partially duplicate records. The CTE is way slower (12 sec) as the INNER JOIN approach (4 sec).

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you are trying to do, using a `Stored Procedure` which returns a query result. `Views` are not suitable / developed for operations like this one.

Comment: Be warned: creating a temporary table inside a stored procedure will cause that procedure to be **recompiled** (since the schema changes), and filling it with data might cause a **second recompile** (since statistics changed). This is not a very good approach.....

Comment: My answer is for if it's ok to use views in such cases. I'm not trying to give the most optimized solution here. My answer applies to any case with more than a single SELECT query.

Comment: I don't see why it's "not a very good approach" just because your Stored Proc gets recompiled twice... What's the problem with that exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible but if you try CTE, this would be the code:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VW_PuntosDeControlDeExpediente]
AS
    WITH TEMP (RefLocal, IdPuntoControl, Descripcion) 
    AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              EX.RefLocal
            , PV.IdPuntoControl
            , PV.Descripcion
        FROM [dbo].[PuntosDeControl] AS PV
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vertidos] AS VR ON VR.IdVertido = PV.IdVertido
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ExpedientesMF] AS MF ON MF.IdExpedienteMF = VR.IdExpedienteMF
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Expedientes] AS EX ON EX.IdExpediente = MF.IdExpediente
    )
    SELECT 
          Q1.[RefLocal]
        ,    [IdPuntoControl] = ( SELECT MAX(IdPuntoControl) FROM TEMP WHERE [RefLocal] = Q1.[RefLocal] AND [Descripcion] = Q1.[Descripcion] )
        , Q1.[Descripcion]
    FROM TEMP AS Q1
    GROUP BY Q1.[RefLocal], Q1.[Descripcion]
GO
```

Comment: `WITH TEMP` is defining a CTE, not a temporary table.

Comment: Ok yes, but is the same functionallity

Comment: Mostly, but not exactly. For example, if you are trying to steer the planner in a certain direction by forcing the temp table creation. The planner will do whatever it feels like with whatever the CTE describes (usually a good thing, but not always).

Comment: Can you explain this more concretely? Thanks

Comment: @ÁngelIbáñez This is not what the OP is asking. I would change your answer to something like: "No, you can't but in CTE it looks like this...."

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @marek-grzenkowicz you can solve this by an CTE. There is also an alternatively which is not obvious. You can create an inner function where you can use tables variables.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.myFunc
()
RETURNS @table TABLE
(
  [ID]   INT        NULL
, [Name] VARCHAR(3) NULL
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE @temporary1 TABLE
  (
    [ID]   INT        NULL
  , [Name] VARCHAR(3) NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO @temporary1 (ID, Name)
  VALUES (1, 'Foo')
       , (2, 'Bar');

  DECLARE @temporary2 TABLE
  (
    [ID]   INT        NULL
  , [Name] VARCHAR(3) NULL
  );


  INSERT INTO @temporary2 (ID, Name)
  VALUES (3, 'Foo')
       , (4, 'Bar');

  INSERT INTO @table (ID, Name)
  SELECT *
  FROM @temporary1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM @temporary2;

  RETURN;
END;
```

And next you can use this function in your view.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.myView
AS
  SELECT ID
       , Name
  FROM dbo.myFunc ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another SQL view instead of a temporary table and then referencing it in the main SQL view. In other words, a view within a view. You can then drop the first view once you are done creating the main view.

Comment: how/where do you drop the first view