# Joining two CTE's take long time but pure temp table does not

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling with query that takes long time.
Just briefly, I have got two CTE's that have not much data and joining them take long time (about 10 seconds).
But when I pack each cte into pure temp table like this:

```
with cte as (...)
select * into tbl_cte from cte
```

and then join temp tables, everything works very fast.

I can't understand why this approach is faster. I don't use either an identity column or primary key on temp tables.

Comment: check execution plans - the table could have out of date statistics, leading to a poor execution plan - or it could just be pure bad luck that the execution plan for the CTE is not as good as the temp table.

Comment: CTEs aren't tables, temporary or otherwise. They are just subqueries. Hence, there's absolutely no point in comparing joins between two tables and joins between subqueries. A subquery does the job your code did to *load* the data into the temporary table. Did you include that in the comparison?

Comment: Without the executions plans we can't really help.  Use this [paste the plan link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to share the plans for the various approaches

Comment: rather that giving your query as `...`, which is utterly useless to every volunteer here, actually provide the full SQL. Otherwise we have no idea what your SQL is doing. The execution plan(s) will also really help. [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: The database engine has a couple different ways to deal with CTE's.  It may choose to do them as a join - which you want -   or as a subquery on each row -  which becomes much slower.  You can't always force one or the other.  Excuse me for tooting my own duplicate horn:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143372/why-is-this-cte-so-much-slower-than-using-temp-tables/24152879#24152879.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this CTE so much slower than using temp tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143372/why-is-this-cte-so-much-slower-than-using-temp-tables)

Comment: You'll see what the database engine chose to do in Execution Plans.  If you haven't used the Plans before,  here is a (long but clear)  introduction to what they mean and how to look at them:  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/  .     And here is the shorter version on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan