# UNION two tables with conditions from the first

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a union on the same table `[MyTable]` so I can select certain values as the top 5, the logic of which I'm excluding here to simplify the question (I hope):

The first table I alias as `tbl1` - can I reference this alias somehow after the UNION statement so that I can exclude the results from it?

I tried like so but it doesn't recognise `tbl1`

```
SELECT top 5 tbl1.Id, tbl1.Description, 'first'
  FROM (
           -- query [MyTable] joined with others to get particular result set
       ) as tbl1

UNION

SELECT tbl2.Id, tbl2.Description, 'second'
  FROM [MyTable] as tbl2 WHERE tbl2.Id NOT IN
     (SELECT Id FROM tbl1)
```

Or do I just have to redo the first query in the 2nd half in order to get those Id's to exclude?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 for this.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: I guess I'd have to include the omitted selection logic for part 1 for that to make any sense.

Comment: @jamheadart . . . I would suggest asking another question with more detail, because there is possibly a simpler (and more performant) way to write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT top 5 tbl1.Id, tbl1.Description, 'first'
  FROM (
           -- query [MyTable] joined with others to get particular result set
  ) as tbl1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl2.Id, tbl2.Description, 'second'
FROM [MyTable] as tbl2 WHERE tbl2.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM cte)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a temp table for the same purpose based on your requirement. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690465/which-are-more-performant-cte-or-temporary-tables).

```
SELECT TOP 5 tbl1.Id, tbl1.Description, 'first' INTO #tbl1
FROM (
           -- query [MyTable] joined with others to get particular result set
) 

SELECT * FROM #tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl2.Id, tbl2.Description, 'second'
FROM [MyTable] AS tbl2 
WHERE tbl2.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM #tbl1)
```

Comment: Up-voted cos I did consider this but it was an in-line query somewhere so thought against it.