# How to select a Name in an List?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this sample table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Table]
(
    [Person] [nchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person_Table] ([Person])
VALUES ('Ken, Brian, Mike,')
       ('Mikem, Briane, Kenny,')
```

If I want to look for Mike with this:

```
DECLARE @Person nvarchar(200)
SET @Person = 'Mike'

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[dbo].[Person_Table]
WHERE Person LIKE '%' + @Person + '%'
```

Then I get the second row too. But it should not be. Is there are better way to get only the first row with Mike?

Result table:
[image]

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: This is what i did.

Comment: And what about  #4?

Comment: Can you help with the question?

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single  column

Comment: Martin its not the answer to the question

Comment: The best answer to the question is "don't do that"

Comment: @MisterXAGE_ Yes, it is, and it's the best answer.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You've stored the data in a manner that's an anti-pattern.  For example, you can't simply index your search. If normalised, however, you Can EASILY index the search.

For example...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person_list]
(
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  list NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO
  [dbo].[person_list] (list)
VALUES
  (N'Ken, Brian, Mike,')
  (N'Mikem, Briane, Kenny,')
;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[person]
(
  id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  person NVARCHAR(100),
  person_list_id INT
);

INSERT INTO
  [dbo].[person] (person, person_list_id)
VALUES
  (N'Ken', 1),
  (N'Brian', 1),
  (N'Mike', 1),
  (N'Mikem', 2),
  (N'Briane', 2),
  (N'Kenny', 2)
;

SELECT
  *
FROM
  person_list
INNER JOIN
  person
    ON person.person_list_id = person_list.id
WHERE
  person.person = N'Mike'
```

If you MUST stick with your broken structure, you CAN do this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  person_table
WHERE
  N', ' + person LIKE N'%, Mike, %' 
  -- Assumes the person column is ALWAYS terminated with ', ' as per your example
```

Which will perform like shit on larger tables, be a maintenence headache, and break if you ever get names like `Mike, Jr`

***EDIT:***

Or, tidying up a `string_split()` example (but having the exact same problems as the `LIKE` version...)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  person_table
CROSS APPLY
  string_split(replace(person_table.person, N', ', N',') N',') AS person
WHERE
  person.value = N'Mike'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Your data resembles a JSON array.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Person NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Person) VALUES 
('Ken, Brian, Mike'),
('Mikem, Briane, Kenny');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Person NVARCHAR(100) = 'Mike';

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
WHERE @Person in (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Person,', ','","'), '"]')));
```

**Output**

```
+---+------------------+
| 1 | Ken, Brian, Mike |
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Its a good start. Are there something more simple?

Comment: I don't understand your irony. A simple `SELECT` is not simple enough?

Comment: @MisterXAGE_, please, check the `', ' + Person + ' ' like '%, ' + @Person + ', %'` approach

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options you can try.

You could use SQL Server's `string_split` function and use `=` instead of `like`

```
SELECT *
FROM Person_Table p
where exists (select * from String_Split(Replace(p.person,', ',','),',')s where s.value=@Person)
```

An even simpler way would be as follows, all depending on your real-world data as to whether it's suitable but add a separator character to both the searched expression and input expression:

```
DECLARE @Person nvarchar(100)
SET @Person = Concat('Mike',',')

SELECT *
FROM Person_Table
WHERE Concat(Person,',') LIKE Concat('%',@Person,'%')
```

Comment: The last example should add the separator to the start as well as the end *(though the OP's example already has the separator at the end of the values in the table)*. This prevents `'Sir Mike, Sir Fu, Sir Bar, '` being matched by `'Mike'`

Answer (score 0):

This **String_split** seems to work.
Can someone understand why I get the data for both year, although i just enter 2020?

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Table]
    (
      Person nvarchar(500) NULL, 
      Name2 nvarchar(500), 
      Year_N int
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Person_Table (Person, Name2, [Year_N])
VALUES ('Ken,Brian,Mike,','A,B,','2000'),
       ('Mikem,Briane,Kenny,','C,D,','2020'),
       ('Dodo,Chris,Mike,','A,B,','2020');

-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Person NVARCHAR(100) = 'Mike',
        @Date int = 2020

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[dbo].[Person_Table]
WHERE EXISTS 
              (Select * from string_split(Person,',') 
               WHERE value in (@Person))
              
OR EXISTS     (Select * from string_split(Name2,',') 
               WHERE value in (@Person))

AND Year_N = @Date
```

Comment: Operator order of precedence...  `A OR B AND C` is  more explicitly `(A) OR (B AND C)`.  So, you need to add the brackets to explicitly be `(A OR B) AND C`

Comment: Also, if you're using `string_split()`, you removal of the spaces in the data is a good idea, but you should also remove the trailing `,`

Comment: For example, `(','+person LIKE '%,'+@person+',%' OR ','+name2 LIKE '%,'+@person+',%') AND Year_N = @Date`

Answer (score 0):

To filter in lists, append the separator both in the hay and the needle:

```
DECLARE @Person nvarchar(200)
SET @Person = 'Mike'

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Person_Table]
WHERE ', ' + Person + ' ' LIKE '%, ' + @Person + ', %'
```

Here's a corresponding fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f64d30/2

A warning note, though: this approach will always yield a full table scan.

Answer (score -2):

Just giving some possibilities for you and it is your choice what method you use
Used String_SPLIT() function to split the string and used a temp table to get the name filtered.

1st Way: You can use Temp, CTE, Derived Table to handle your data. It is up to you to decide which way is required as this shows one possibility:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Table]
 (
  [Person] [nchar](100) NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person_Table] ([Person])
 VALUES ('Ken, Brian, Mike,')
 ,  ('Mikem, Briane, Kenny,')


 SELECT  RTRIM(LTRIM([Value])) AS  [Person]
 INTO #Temp_Data
 FROM [Person_Table]  
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Person], ',');  

 --Filter from what you need:

 SELECT * FROM #Temp_Data
 WHERE [Person]  = 'Mike'
```

[image]

2nd possibility:

Using CHARINDEX to find the start of the Exact Word you need to find and then filter by your Value. Value that you want to filter can be used with a variable as you don't need to hardcode it over and over again.

```
  SELECT
    A.Person
  FROM
 (
  SELECT   SUBSTRING( Person,  CHARINDEX('Mike,' ,[Person], 0 ),  
   LEN('MIKE'))AS  [Value] 
   , Person
  FROM [Person_Table]  

  ) AS A WHERE A.[Value]= 'Mike'
```

[image]

Comment: That would copy the name list from Every Single Row in the table. That is a Very bad practice.  Use a CTE instead of a Temp table.

Comment: What  is the difference between CTE and Temp table. Performance wise Temp is best you can focus on your solution while others focus on their solutions. I am helping the person to solve his issue, The person who has the question will consider.

Comment: You need to increase your knowledge about SQL query perfomance. We are not aware of the actual problem of the person who asks the question. 
but we still try to provide answers. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690465/which-are-more-performant-cte-or-temporary-tables 
Temp tables can be used to show sample answers.
it is best when handling large datasets and tarsnformations as it is handled by temp memory and do 
the work and deallocate.
Check your answer, re-inserting same things over and over again.  First Learn ethics in codding and best parctices.

Comment: As you wish, I stand by every comment made here.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Your 2nd possibility does not run; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee9e7e6abae95e4aac87199aee2b7033

Comment: Let me check. Seems a typo

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for showing me the issue. It was a typo when I was formatting.  Thanks for  noticing this.