How can I optimize this query? Taking far too long to execute
The following query takes almost 2 minutes to run.  I'm dealing with large tables yet even after indexing still takes too long.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated (execute plan below)
DECLARE @FromDate datetime
DECLARE @ToDate datetime
DECLARE @SSNumber int
SET @FromDate = '2023-03-01'
SET @ToDate = '2023-07-01'
SET @SSNumber = -1

DECLARE @CareDates TABLE(CareDate datetime, DOW varchar(20))
DECLARE @curDate datetime
DECLARE @curDOW varchar(20)

SET @curDate = @FromDate

WHILE DATEDIFF(day, @curDate, @ToDate + 1) > 0
BEGIN
     SET @curDOW = DATENAME(dw, @curDate)
     INSERT INTO @CareDates (CareDate, DOW) VALUES (@curDate, @curDOW)

     SET @curDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @curDate)
     PRINT DATEDIFF(day, @curDate, @ToDate)
END;

WITH personal_care AS
(
     SELECT PersonalCareID, SSNumber, ItemCode, CareSchedule, IsCurrent, StartDate
          , DATEADD(DAY, -1, (ISNULL(LEAD(StartDate,1) OVER (
              PARTITION BY SSNumber, ItemCode
              ORDER BY SSNumber, ItemCode, StartDate), '9999-12-31'))) AS EndDate
     FROM HOMEResidentPersonalCare
)

SELECT PC.PersonalCareID, 
    CD.CareDate, 
    CD.DOW, 
    PC.SSNumber, 
    PC.ItemCode, 
    PC.CareSchedule, 
    PC.IsCurrent, 
    PC.StartDate, 
    PC.EndDate, 
    PCS.CareScheduleID, 
    PCS.[Shift], 
    PCS.EmployeeID,
    HRPCP.CareProvidedID, 
    ISNULL(HRPCP.Status,'I') AS CareStatus
FROM @CareDates CD
CROSS JOIN personal_care PC 
INNER JOIN HomeResidentPersonalCareSchedule PCS ON PCS.PersonalCareID = PC.PersonalCareID AND (PCS.DayOfWeek = CD.DOW OR PCS.DayOfWeek = 'All')
LEFT JOIN HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided HRPCP ON HRPCP.CareTypeID = PC.ItemCode AND HRPCP.SSNumber = PC.SSNumber AND HRPCP.[Shift] = PCS.[Shift] AND HRPCP.CareDate = CD.CareDate
WHERE CD.CareDate BETWEEN PC.StartDate AND PC.EndDate
AND (HRPCP.Status IS NULL OR HRPCP.Status <> 'D')

Execution Plan

This is actually the core of an even more involved query (with additional table joins), but even this is extremely sluggish, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong

It would probably help if you could break the query down into a couple of individual parts to assess their impact, and isolate the timings on each of those - 1) how long does the insert into @CareDates take?  2) How long does the CTE query take on its own?

What improvement do you see if you set a PRIMARY KEY against "CareDate" in the @CareDates table?

Have you run this with "Anaylze Query in Database Tuning Advisor" to see what suggestions come from that?  Without having the access to your actual database, it could be difficult for others to pinpoint where actual improvements might be made

Generally, if you use table variables (instead of temp tables), you don't get all the bells and whistles that the optimizer can do for you.  Consider using a temp table instead.

What version of SQL Server are you running?

FYI: PRIMARY KEY ON CareDate didn't affect performance.  If I leave query as is but leave out the join on HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided, it runs in 2 seconds.  I used  to use temporary tables, but it was sometimes a hassle when the table didn't get dropped and the query ran again because it said temp table already existed

You can easily add a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CareDates at the beginning to not have to worry about pre-existing artefacts from previous failed runs

RE: Your edit. The "revised query" is not the same as the original query. You should ask a new question about that, CTEs don't "store data" though, if you want to break up the query into different parts you should use #temp tables - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690465/which-are-more-performant-cte-or-temporary-tables/26205087#26205087 for more about that

Revised extended query can now be found at this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78535782/could-use-ideas-to-further-optimize-this-extended-query

Any reason not to "accept" one of the answers

The query execution took 1 min 35 seconds.
1 min 33 seconds of that was spent by the index seek operator on HOMEResidentPersonalCareProvided and associated key lookup operator.

Option 1 - better indexing
This will be hugely sped up by the index below
CREATE INDEX IX_HRPCP_Whatever 
ON HOMEResidentPersonalCareProvided (SSNumber,CareTypeID, CareDate , Shift) 
INCLUDE (Status, CareProvidedID)

The seek operator on IX_HRPCP_Optimize1 takes 1 min 32 seconds and reads 412,338,970 rows across all executions to return 404,027 as it only seeks on two columns SSNumber, CareTypeID and needs to evaluate the CareDate with a residual predicate.
Adding Shift as a key column in the index also allows that to be evaluated at the same time (currently done as a residual in the key lookup).
Finally adding the include columns makes the index covering and avoids the need for key lookups for the 227,664 rows that do match all four conditions.
You have four equality conditions so any ordering of the four key columns in the index works equally well for this query.
Option 2 - better estimates
The table cardinality of HOMEResidentPersonalCareProvided is only 2,166,440 rows though and 227,664 is a reasonable percentage of that so you could also forget about optimising for index seeks and just settle for a hash join with an equality on all four of the columns.
You can add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of the query so that it takes into account the cardinality of the table variable and see if it now gives you that plan anyway (or at least a much better plan!).

You are on SQL Server 2019 so table variable deferred compilation could have mitigated that issue for you anyway but you are using  CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" so this isn't available to you (presumably due to a lower database compatibility level blocking this).

Option #1 definitely made a major improvement (the COMPLETE  query now runs in about 10 seconds!).  However, I already had a four separate non-clustered indexes for each of those columns.  How does  that differ from one index that is composed of all four and can I now get rid of  the four individual indexes?

OPTION RECOMPILE also made a big difference

is OPTION RECOMPILE not only needed when (a lot of) the data has changed?

The purpose of OPTION (RECOMPILE) here is because the whole batch is compiled before any statements are executed. So the statement using the table variable will be compiled before any rows have been inserted to it and it will assume a single row will be output from it. The  OPTION (RECOMPILE)  forces a recompile after the inserts have happened and so it can see how many rows it contains. This is similar to what the deferred compilation does but the OP is using a lower compat level so that isn't available. They could also use a #temp table instead to get cardinality based recompiles.

4 separate indexes are completely different from a single index over 4 columns... if the 4 columns are required for a query then the single columns indexes aren't helpful... FOR that query only - don't just remove them unless you have determined they aren't also used elsewhere. The 4 column index will only replace the index which matches the first column.

Based on a manual analysis of your query and plan, I have a couple of suggestions.
(1) Make sure you have indexes to support your joins. It looks like your query would benefit from indexes on the following (or similar).

personal_care(StartDate, EndDate)
HomeResidentPersonalCareSchedule(PersonalCareID, DayOfWeek) INCLUDE(CareScheduleID, Shift, EmployeeID)
HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided(CareTypeID, SSNumber, Shift, CareDate) INCLUDE(Status, CareProvidedID)

Check to see what indexes you already have defines and try adding the above if not present.
The INCLUDEd columns are optional. For HomeResidentPersonalCareSchedule, they provide all the data needed by the query, without the need for a table lookup (clustered index seek). For HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided, they help with filtering the data before the associated table lookup (clustered index seek) occurs. These included columns can instead be added to the indexed column list or omitted entirely - whatever is your preference.
If CareScheduleID is the primary-key/clustered-index for HomeResidentPersonalCareSchedule, that column can be omitted from the above index, as the clustered index key is implicitly included in every index.  Same for CareProvidedID and HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided.
(2) Rearrange your query placing the personal_care table first with an initial WHERE condition that filters for an overlap between the StartDate..EndDate range and the @FromDate..@Todate range. A standard test for overlapping inclusive date ranges is Start1 <= End2 AND Start2 <= End1. This will require an initial index scan on the personal_care(StartDate, EndDate) index followed by a single lookup of the eligible personal_care rows. (I expect this will yield a significant performance improvement.)
The updated query would look like:
SELECT ...
FROM personal_care PC
INNER JOIN @CareDates CD 
    ON CD.CareDate BETWEEN PC.StartDate AND PC.EndDate
INNER JOIN HomeResidentPersonalCareSchedule PCS
    ON PCS.PersonalCareID = PC.PersonalCareID
    AND PCS.DayOfWeek IN (CD.DOW, 'ALL')
LEFT JOIN HomeResidentPersonalCareProvided HRPCP
    ON HRPCP.CareTypeID = PC.ItemCode
    AND HRPCP.SSNumber = PC.SSNumber
    AND HRPCP.[Shift] = PCS.[Shift]
    AND HRPCP.CareDate = CD.CareDate
WHERE (PC.StartDate <= @ToDate AND PC.EndDate >= @FromDate) -- Overlap
AND (HRPCP.Status IS NULL OR HRPCP.Status <> 'D')

The @CareDates table is now referenced second. I moved the join condition from the WHERE clause to the ON condition. I also changed the PCS.DayOfWeek test to use IN (CD.DOW, 'ALL'). I don't think that makes a difference, but is more compact.
(3) Add PRIMARY KEY to the @CareDates table. This might give a slight improvement in the join.
(4) If you are using SQL Server 2022, you can use the GENERATE_SERIES() function to populate your @CareDates table without a loop.
INSERT INTO @CareDates (CareDate, DOW)
SELECT D.CareDate, DATENAME(dw, D.CareDate)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)) S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(day, S.value, @FromDate) AS CareDate) D

This is likely not a performance bottleneck, but is offered up as a way to populate that table using a single set operation. For earlier SQL Server versions, there are other techniques for generating ranges, but I wouldn't bother with that for now if you are not on 2022.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo of the above date range generator.
That's all I've got for now. I hope this helps. If it still seems slower than expected after these suggestions have been applied, post an updated execution plan and someone can take another look.
Bonus: (5) Sometimes, if we set everything up and craft the query to give SQL Server everything it needs for efficient execution, it may still look at the statistics and joins and chose something less efficient. In particular, the join order of the personal_care and @CareDates might be reversed. As a fallback, when this happens, I sometimes add OPTION(FORCE ORDER) to the end of the query to tell SQL Server to "execute it the way I wrote it". (Best used sparingly.)
